# Status Code 480 - Secure Connection Failed

Tags: python, bots, telegram, replit

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the actual token you obtained from BotFather
TOKEN = 'the token is secret'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your bot.')

def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Command handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Message handler for echoing messages
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))
    updater.start_polling()
    @app.route('/')
    def show_url():
     return jsonify({"url": f"https://{os.environ['REPL_SLUG']}.{os.environ['REPL_OWNER']}.repl.co"})
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
print("Bot is running!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the bot opened a webview for me, with a link, but when I try to enter the link on a hosting site, it writes me an error 480:

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent : Site24x7
Cache-Control : no-cache
Accept : */*
Connection : Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding : gzip

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent : Site24x7
Cache-Control : no-cache
Accept : */*
Connection : Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding : gzip

And apparently, when I open the link that the bot emits in the webview, it should show me "Bot is running!"
, but it shows me the link as it shows me in webview.

What is the fault?